# How to position a graphic button using layers

Tags: css

I have this page (below), and I want to position a graphical button on the bottom right of the screenshot (right of the prices)

How can I do this with a few lines of code?

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="content-1g">
    <div class="content-1-1g">
        </div>
    <div class="content-1-2g"><p class="none"><%# Eval("TName")%></p>
            <div class="content-1-3g"><p><%# Eval("TDetails")%></p></div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Adult: £<%# Eval("TPriceadult")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Senior/Student: £<%# Eval("TPricesenior")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Child: £<%# Eval("TPricechild")%> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-1g {
    float: left;
    width: 836px;
    padding: 0px 32px 0px 32px;
/*  background-color: White;
    border: 1px solid orange; */
}

.content-1-1g 
{
    float: left;
    width: 269px;
    height: 202px;
    margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url('../images/Chinatown-experience-logo.png') no-repeat left top;
}

.content-1-2g {
    float: right;
    /*width: 591px; */
    width: 547px;
    padding: 0px 00px 0px 0px;
    font: 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.content-1-3g {
    float: right;
    /*width: 591px; */
    width: 547px;
    padding: 0px 00px 0px 0px;
    font: 100% "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Thanks
Tea

Answer (score 0):

The one with "Chinatown" caption is a button?

You can position it absolute, and set the right and bottom values for it:

```
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
```

Comment: nope that just a background graphic on .content-1-1g.  I'm not showing the button, it's a small button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split the product specifications in two divs and float them left and right. Something like this:

```
<div class="content-1g">
<div class="content-1-1g">

</div>
<div class="content-1-2g">
    <p class="none"><%# Eval("TName")%></p>
    <div class="content-1-3g"><p><%# Eval("TDetails")%></p></div>
    <div class="content-left">
            <div class="content-1-3g">Adult: £<%# Eval("TPriceadult")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Senior/Student: £<%# Eval("TPricesenior")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Child: £<%# Eval("TPricechild")%> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
        <!-- Your button -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the CSS:

```
.content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 273px;
}

.content-right {
    float: left;
    width: 273px;
}
```

Size the right div at the width of your button. Hope it helps!

Comment: that is the way I thought.  But is there an easier way?

Comment: I am afraid not, unless you want to use minus margins (is not recommend because not all browser support that) or work with position: absolute, but that's not the way to do this because you work with floats in your document.

Answer (score 0):

put this button at the end of the text, and then:

```
.your_button {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```